# Why operators (tap, map) are not called on inner observable, when using combineLatest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

Why are operators `tap` and `map` of inner observable not called? `combineLatest` should subscribe to observables it gets in `obsArr`, right? Why this subscription does not trigger those operators?

```
const obsArr = [];

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].map(arr => {

  const observable = from(arr);

  observable.pipe(
    tap(item => {
      // this is NOT called
      console.log('tap', item)
    }),
    map(item => {
      // this is NOT called
      return item * -1;
    })
  );

  obsArr.push(observable);
});

combineLatest(obsArr).subscribe(latestValues => {
  console.log(latestValues);
  // LOG: [2, 4, 5]
  // LOG: [2, 4, 6]
});
```

Working stackblitz: https://rxjs-y2h4rn.stackblitz.io

Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding pipe to the observable, but pushing the original Observable to the array. Instead you should push the modified observable:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].map(arr => {

  const observable = from(arr);

  obsArr.push(observable.pipe(
    tap(item => {
      console.log('tap', item)
    }),
    map(item => {
      return item * -1;
    })
  ));
});
```